# play different frames onclick flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have 2 symbols in a frame: deer and man.
I want to stop the flash movie on frame 45 
and if user clicks on deer play frames 50-100
but if user clicks on man I want to play frame
200 - 250. The code I have in frame 45 is:

```
stop();
var _buttons:Array = [deer, man];

for(var i = 0; i < _buttons.length; i++){
    _buttons[i].onRelease = function() {
        gotoAndPlay(100);
    }

    _buttons[i].onRelease = function() {
        gotoAndPlay(200);
    }
}
```

when movie stops on frame 45 and I click on an object nothing happens but there are no errors.

Comment: Try to remove `private` word before `function`.

Comment: then i get error `interface 'MouseEvent' could not be loaded.`

Comment: There needs to be an `import flash.events.MouseEvent` before the rest of your code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I get error `interface 'flash.events.MouseEvent' could not be loaded.` ?

Comment: This seems to be some idiosyncrasy of AS2, something I stopped putting my head to long ago. If you're making something new, why not use AS3?

Comment: Yeah, I think I will scrap this and go to AS3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
deer.onRelease = function() {
   this.gotoAndPlay(50);
   // make sure that is an stop(); Action on frame 100
}

man.onRelease = function() {
   this.gotoAndPlay(200);
   // make sure that is an stop(); Action on frame 250
}
```

How you named the sensitiv Moviclip or Button - "deer" & "man" ? It's better you works with named Frames not with frame number. Goto a keyframe a rename the keyframe. Then you can write for example: this.gotoAndPlay("man_start");

You tag it as AS2 - I hope I can help you.
Best regards

EDIT: Make sure that you have the right path for the gotoAndPlay. You can write for example _root.gotoAndPlay("man_start") when the Button/clip on the root timline. If the button is in the man clip you can write for example:

```
deer.your_named_button.onRelease = function() {
    this._parent.gotoAndPlay("man_start");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer but I must be doing something wrong. I did everything you said but I have everything in one layer. And I am putting this script in the action-frame panel. Maybe that is also a problem?

Comment: Okay - you have every item on one timeline and not in a clip - right?

Comment: yeah, everything is in the timeline

Comment: Okay - on this timeline you have the items - deer and man. Are you convert it as an Movieclip or as an button?

Comment: Try: Make a new layer called Markers and a new layer called actions. On the layer actions you set a empty keyframe (F6) on the frames 0, 50, 100, 200, 250 and write in every keyframe (0, 50, 100, 200, 250) the action: stop(); On the markers layer you set the empty keyframes in frame 0, 100, 200. Klick on every keyframe (that not choosen a clip or something else - only the keyframe) and name the frame 0 "start", frame 100 "play_deer", frame 200 "play_man".

Comment: I read now " I want to stop the flash movie on frame 45 " Are the buttons on frame 45 ? Then you must write the button-action on the same framenumbers - if you want to give a button a action the button must be available on the timeline - button on frame 33/action on frame 0 doesn't work. button on frame 45/action on farme 45 works.

Comment: Yeah, the buttons are on 45, I followed your instructions, it took me some time to figure out how to name keyframes. I did it by window>other panel>accesibility, is that right?

Comment: No - it's on same place you set name for a movieclip or a button. You click not on a clip - you click on your keyframe and write the name you like. After that : In your keyframe you see a flag and your typed name. You know what I mean? Sorry for my bad english ;-) And the button action must now on the frame 45. When you call the action the button must be on this frame available.

Comment: I just figured out the name, wow I feel silly I had a different window convering that exact spot this whole time sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ActionScript 2, the issue you run into is a classic object scope related problem.  It is not ActionScript 2 fault, but JavaScript specification.  Consider the following snippet

```
trace(this);  // it displays the movieclip that hosts the button
myButton.onRelease = function() {
    trace(this);  //oops, it is the button, not the host.
}
```

One quick hack to get around this without resorting to _root would be

```
stop();
var _buttons:Array = [deer, man];

trace("deer button: " + deer);
deer.context = this;
deer.onRelease = function() {
    trace("deer button is clicked.");
    deer.context.gotoAndPlay(100);
}

trace("man button: " + deer);
man.onRelease = function() {
    trace("man button is clicked.");
    man.context.gotoAndPlay(200);
}
```

A much more elegant implementation would be using [delegate](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/205/1/The-Delegate-Class/Page1.html), so you don't have to hard-code _root or "context" properties.

Comment: I pasted this exactly and only changed name for button but I have same problem?

Comment: Well, let's make sure that the button event is consumed.  I have updated the code above, so you may see if the trace statement is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can write in the action panel from the first keyframe("start", keyframe 0):

```
stop(); // you have write it in the first step

// klick on your deer button and name it "deer_btn", if isn't it
deer_btn.onRelease = function() {
    _root.gotoAndPlay("play_deer");
    trace("I pressed deer_btn"); // can you delete later
}

// klick on your man button and name it "man_btn", if isn't it
man_btn.onRelease = function() {
    _root.gotoAndPlay("play_man");
    trace("I pressed man_btn"); // can you delete later
}
```

This should be work, but it's untested. No Flash on the notebook. I hope it helps you. May not - ask me.

Comment: I don't know. I can't see it, what you are doing - sorry. How Tianzhen Lin write I think it's really a scope problem. Are you get the notices "I pressed ..." Then you know that your buttons starts the action and this part is correctly. 
Now I must go to eat and will be back tommorow. Good Luck!